# Spring web.xmlのerror-pageを正常に動かす方法について

Tags: spring

SpringMVCの勉強で例外ハンドリングを勉強しています。
ExceptionHandleメソッドでは正常に表示されていたエラー画面が、なぜかweb.xmlのerror-pageでは正常に動作せず、HTTP 500のページが表示されてしまいます。

HTTP 500のページが表示されているので、error-pageで指定したlocationを表示しようとしてると思うのですが、なぜか内部エラーとなってしまい原因がわからない状態です。
どのような対処をすればよいのでしょうか・・・？

例外を発生させるメソッド

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, params="send2")
public String output2(@RequestParam String text) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("TEST******"+text);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

ExceptionHandlerメソッド

```
@ExceptionHandler
public String handleException(Exception e) {
    return "error/systemError";
}
```

web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/systemError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

※configureViewResolvers

```
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".jsp");
}
```

Comment: HTTP 500(内部エラー)なら、まずはログを見た方がいいです。

Comment: STSのコンソールに出力されるログを見ましたが、違いと言えば「重大: Servlet.service() for servlet [xxxx] in context with path [/xxxx] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception] with root cause」が赤字で出力されるぐらいです・・・。原因例外も追加してみましたが変化なしでした・・・。Tomcatのログもアクセスログしか見つけれていません・・・。ログの見る場所ちがうのでしょうか・・・(初歩的すぎてすみません)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました・・・

結論から言うと、IEの「HTTP エラーメッセージを簡易表示する」の設定がONになっていることが原因でした。

しかし、error-pageを指定すると↓となり
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

設定しないと↓となるのが理解できないところです・・・
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]